# Managing guest API consumption with Vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, security

I'm actually trying to find my way securing my Laravel7 API.

Here is a quick scheme of the API consumption process I want to achieve:

1st scenario, Guest user browsing public routes:

1. Guest User (1st visit, local storage empty)
2. => Vuejs App try to generate Guest access_token before anything else
3. => CORS secured API call to api/login with { "guest":true }
4. => API respond with a access_token linked to a global Guest User with limited scopes
5. => Vuejs store the access_token in local storage
6. => Axios reacts to the new access_token and setup for all future calls to use it
7. => Vuejs boot up
8. => Guest user can browse the public routes with all calls using the guest access_token

2nd scenario, Guest user log in using Firebase Auth:

1. Guest user (with his guest access_token) logs in using FirebaseUI (firebase auth)
2. => returned Google access_token is sent to the API for verification
3. => API verify the google's token validity (using firebase-php) and respond with a access_token linked to a existing user by google's uid (or create one if not)
4. => Axios reacts to the new access_token and setup for all future calls to use it
5. => Vuejs reload
6. => Logged user can browse all the routes available for this token's scopes

Firstly, I wanted to know what you think about the security logic applied here. I am trying to use guest signing in addition to domain origin CORS in order to make sure that only my app can access the API.

The problem is that due to Axios asynchronous request I am having hard time getting my Guest access_token before my vueJS app boot and makes calls without access_token (local storage being empty at that moment).

Is there a way to make sure that a global variable or localstorage or even cookie containing my Guest access_token is available before Vuejs start booting and setup my Axios plugin ?

Is there a completely different way to do it ? I am taking all advices, thanks.

Comment: So, for now, I am relying on Vuex to store my Guest's access_token and will not make any call without check for a access_token in my store and if not present, I watch for its reception. The token's scopes will take care of the kind of token given.